# Should I ask for a pay raise for employees I manage?

Tags: salary

I talked with one of my team members about another guy who is quitting. During the talk, he mentioned that it might be because there was no pay raise for the past 2 years. These guys (one who I was talking to and another guy who is quitting) are very good at their job, work hard, and love the company and I think it's unfair not to give them any pay raise. I also think that this can actually be the reason why people are quitting.

I want to give background of the company. The company is a startup and there is no procedure about pay raise. As a startup, we need to save money wherever we can but this really affects the company because we actually end up spending more money recruiting people and time to train them.

I plan to talk to the owner (I report to him) about pay raise for everyone in my team but not sure if that is a good idea.

I am their manager and I got a good raise every year.
I did not know that they never got a raise until yesterday. The owner takes care of pay raises. Since I have gotten good raises, I assumed everyone else did.

Comment: Has the employee who is quitting ever brought the lack of pay to conversation? This would change your approach for how you go about asking your manager. It's one thing for people to work and wait to be acknowledged, but it's another to actually ask your manager for a pay bump (within reason of course). One of the best things I've experienced at a company was having an open communication culture, that made me feel like my manager was actually in my corner when it came to wage conversations.

Comment: "I think it's unfair not to give them any pay raise" - have other teams/personnel (at the same org level) received pay raises, but not this group? In that case, it's unfair. Otherwise, it's as you stated, the finances of the company and a business decision/reality, which is quite different from 'unfair'

Comment: Why do you get a raise (good one), and they don't?

Comment: @AaronF how should he have known that they didn't get raises? (he didn't, as he said in one of the comments)

Comment: Because he is their manager :)

Comment: @IvoBeckers by remembering that he hadn't ever given them raises? If he didn't know, then maybe he's not their manager, but a team leader instead? Or maybe the company is badly run? (I once worked as IT 'manager' for a place where the finance director kept everything a secret. It was impossible to do my job without a budget and I left after less than a year. It later turned out that he had been exaggerating the company's finances, and the period of rapid expansion turned into a period of even more rapid deflation!)

Comment: the term manager is very broad. at least where i'm from. But in most cases it just means (to me) that your manager is someone you report to and someone who makes the decisions about what you work on. And not really about the salary of the people under him.

Answer (score 214):

Yes. As as manager, part of your job is going to bat for the people who work for you, and part of that is asking for pay raises.  Especially if you are getting a good raise, you should be asking (and should have been asking) for a decent raise for your good workers.

If no-one was getting raises, that would be different, but as long as there is money for raises for managers, the manager has an obligation to take care of their workers, and pay raises are a very clear sign on whether an employee is valued or not.

Comment: it's not so much "bat for them" as "bat for your team", which is subtly different. You're not meant to argue for a team member *per say* but, i think, *for the good of the team*. in this way the person you're arguing for then weighs against "good of the company" vs "good for this team".

Comment: @bharal fyi the phrase is *per se*, I believe

Comment: @bharal And really, if you have good employees and a good team, then what is good for the employee will help retain them, which is good for the team, and that is also good for the company.  The raises benefit the company too, since you're keeping the good employees.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek sure, it just makes the manager look different when they argue for it. One positions them as the ceo of a team, the other as caring for team-mates well being. The other thing is that happy team members, while good for the company, might not be as good as a lower burn rate for the company (barring one-off recruiter expenses!), which a vc will care *very* much about.

Comment: @bharal You're very right that could be an issue; however, when you add up the cost to train a new employee to be as effective as the one which left, giving a pay raise can actually reduce the cash burn rate. It depends on how valuable that person's position and experience are to the company as a whole.

Comment: This is right, I'm actually wondering why the OP waited 2 years before thinking of it As a manager I'd be wanting the possibility/probablity of regular raises from the start, it gives me an extra tool to work with and benefits morale all around..

Comment: @Kilisi: I did not know that they never get a raise until yesterday. The owner takes care of pay raise and stuff. Since I have gotten good raises, I assume everyone else does

Comment: @CodeProject , that makes sense

Comment: @CodeProject maybe you should talk about lack of such knowledge too. You should be aware how your team's salaries compare to the market and you can't do without such knowledge. Also keep in mind that replacing a (good) employee usually costs more than offering a raise to the existing one. Only if the employee is seriously overpaid this isn't true.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I have recommended team members for raises in the past and usually this has been fulfilled. You are in the position to make these recommendations - who else would do it? It's a key part of the management role.

Comment: Bear in mind that the reason for the managers pay rise may be that they've been able to maintain a reasonable retention while not having pay rises.

Answer (score 71):

Don't talk to the manager about "a" (singular) pay raise for your staff. Talk to him about what the policy will be for implementing raises - typically, organizations pay out a cost of living increase on a known, regular schedule (ie annually) plus merit increases for strong employees, plus promotion increases when a title changes due to someone taking on more responsibility. It sounds like your organization doesn't have any of these standards in place.

It's fair to represent to the owner that you know of frustrations among the team due to lack of raises recently, but you want to solve the problem for good - not just for now. Getting everyone a raise right now doesn't really do anything except postpone the conversation about raise policy until the next time people get upset.

Comment: This... particularly cost of living increments. 2 years without a pay rise pretty much means your effective income has dropped 4-5% over that time. And you have developers that have gained 2 years experience, and could probably get a 10% hike if they moved.

Comment: Having been in this position (minimal to no pay rise for four years!) the jump when I got a new job out of frustration was pretty impressive. I went from 24k to 28k by moving to a job that was _less_ demanding. Never let an accountant run a company.

Comment: No raise = under-performance.  If you get a D- on a test and nobody tells you why, it tends to piss people off.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 I did the same as well (37 to 53). If your employees recognize that you're going to bat for them as well, you're more likely to have good productivity from them. It's much easier to work knowing your manager has your back in all aspects than to be worried your manager is just out to collect a paycheck.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes.**

- Pay rises will probably be good for your team's morale, which may mean they work more efficiently.
- Pay rises may keep employees in the team, avoiding time and money spent on recruitment to replace those who leave.
- If your team work out that you're standing up for them, they may be more loyal to you, which benefits you personally (now and perhaps in the future) and the company too (if their loyalty to you inspires them to work harder for the company).
- If people are already leaving over pay, your boss needs to know that there is a problem, and what he might need to do about it. In a small company, key people leaving could be an existential threat.
- It would benefit your own career enormously to understand the budget available, perhaps with a view to taking responsibility for it later.

**But...**

- Budget constraints may make it not possible. Replacing staff is more expensive in the long run, but the long run comes later. There might not be enough in the bank to offer rises right now.
- If asking for a rise gets nowhere, or doesn't get enough for your team, **you** will need to act as the face of the company when your team ask about a rise. You can't say "it's not my fault, it's the owner's fault!" You represent the company and may have to deliver - and justify - bad news... *even if you don't agree with the decision... even if you fought against it.*

**And...**

- Might you be able to ***propose other benefits*** that might be almost as valuable to your employees as a rise, but which are more palatable to the owner? Schemes like [Perkbox](https://www.perkbox.com/uk) (I have no affiliation with them, other similar schemes are available) can save your employees money, which isn't as good as *giving* them more money, but costs your company less. Or perhaps arrange partnerships and discount agreements with other local businesses, or get money from the budget for regular social events for your team... that kind of thing. Some of your team might really appreciate the company treating the team to a social trip out once a month... others might say they can't pay rent with 2-4-1 cinema tickets and insist on the pay rise. But it's worth a try.
- As suggested in a comment, if the startup shows promise, some employees may accept stock instead of money. Not all will - it's a gamble - if the company succeeds, the stock may be worth a lot of money later. But if it fails, the stock might be worth zero. Some employees might take the gamble. Others might not.

Comment: Good point that manager will be the face of a company if things will go wrong and will take responsibility. However, discount cards or cinema tickets don't give solid company impression if it can't give decent salary.

Comment: A decent salary is the better option, yes. Lacking that - or in addition to that, why not! - other benefits can feel valuable to employees.

Google offer a great many company benefits, for example, and most of them cost the company very little: http://uk.businessinsider.com/cost-benefit-of-google-perks-2015-4

Comment: It's been a while since I saw a manager defend an apparently bad decision made up higher.  The manager has to deliver the bad news, but not necessarily justify it.  Also, if the startup is promising, handing out stock options might be an incentive.  It's cheap now for the company, if it's temporarily short on funds.

Comment: Good point about stock, I'll edit that in. I think sometimes a manager has to be "the bad guy" and justify company decisions he doesn't agree with, but that's a whole other conversation.

Comment: @BittermanAndy A manager has to hand down company decisions and enforce them, and that can amount to being the bad guy.  Usually, no justification is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should. Ideally, a person should know company politics before joining - what results are expected and what can be achieved. Especially, if you want to work with top performers and people who care about company - if they won't get reward, you'll be left with mediocre who can't find job in other place - and it may cost more.

It is also a question why you're getting a raise and others not. Maybe you are managing team in such way that it is cheap and stable?

There are other things to consider:
If employee will continue to work, is there any room to grow for him in the company?
Can company easily replace an employee? Will extra cost give extra value?
Can old/new employee bring new energy or ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you really need to do is not so much negotiate a pay rise on behalf of your subordinates as to lobby for a system of pay review to be put in place.

The conversation may go along these lines :

- We have a problem in that our pay structure puts us at risk of losing employees to our competitors and may be affecting staff moral.
- I think this is  the case because several of my team have raised it as an issue and A and B have left recently citing this as a particular issue.
- This is costing us money in terms of recruitment costs and lost productivity (give quantitative evidence) .
- Every time a staff member quite it costs us X dollars in recruitment costs and lost productivity whcih is equivalent to a Y% pay rise for all staff.
- Costs in staff productivity are harder to calculate but in may opinion may be even higher.
- Therefore I propose the following...

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, an employee's salary should be a reflection of the value that they bring to the company, which should be defined by their skills. As a manager, if you make a consistent effort to increase the relevant skills that each employee has, then it becomes a very justifiable ask for your management. In two years time, for example, an employee can be far more skilled than when they started and have the capacity to bring much more value to an organization, thus they should be getting paid more. Transparency in this will actually motivate your employees to learn more.

For your specific situation, I would absolutely ask for cost of living raises at a minimum. I'd probably ask for a base line raise of some percentage. Then, I would implement a skill development program to your leadership and tie that to compensation increases.

Answer (score -3):

You should not. You must consider that the reason you got a good raise is because your team did a good job without the owner having to give a raise to everyone. The reason companies gives huge money for board of directors is because it is much cheaper than paying a good salary to everyone as long as they make the employees give more for the same money (or less money or less employees...).

A manage must only take care of their own interests and those of company. You are not a union representative you are a company manager. Good managers suggest downsizing, cutting costs not asking for raises for everyone.

I know this sounds very cynical, but you don't want to be fired do you? And yes, I don't want to have a manager like this, but that is also why employees don't choose their manager.

It also don't mean you need to be a monster to be a good manager. You can and should ask for investment in things that makes employess more productive. It is much cheaper and more effective than giving a raise (whose effect is very short, since people get used to the new level quite fast and start to think they should receive a better income and so on). Most of the times employees leaves they jobs because of bad working conditions, unless your company is paying well bellow the market average.

Comment: A manager who looks out only for themselves and the company will become less effective.  It's usually better to motivate people by getting themselves to align with the company goals than to make demands on them - particularly when the situation is causing expensive turnover.  In this case, the low pay is hurting the team.

Comment: what a terrible answer: dont give them raises, just be selfish

Comment: "employees don't choose their manager" - yes, they do, and the way they do this is by quitting if you don't treat them well. Treat them badly and you end up managing either no-one at all, or only those incapable of getting a job elsewhere.

Answer (score -5):

It really depends on you relationship with the owner and how you go about doing it.

Personally, I would not go ask the owner to give raises to everyone on my team. This is essentially asking the owner to take money out of their own pocket. Remember, this is a start up. There is a very good chance the owner can't afford raises for everyone. I would not do this unless you were willing to take a pay cut in order for them to get the raise.

What I would do is talk to the owner about the fact that you have heard someone is leaving because they have not received a raise. Even go as far as to highlight the loss the company will incur if this person leaves. Then, let the owner decide what the next course of action is.

Comment: maybe my answer isn't clear enough: don't go asking for raises if you don't have a way to recoup the cost. The company is start up and more than likely, can't afford to give everyone yearly raises. Its pretty easy to go in there and ask the owner to take money directly out of their pocket to give to someone else. I wouldn't do that unless I was willing to do the same. Instead, present the issue and let the owner make that decision.

Comment: @Bilkokuya ill try to see if I can edit it. I understand where you were coming from.

Comment: There is no harm in explaining for the owner that this might be a reason people are quitting, you probably wont be sucessful in requiring it though

Comment: @rasan076 that why I said at the end, bring it to their attention. Don't ask for raises, present the problem and let them figure it out

Comment: i think its fine for a manager of a team to argue for raises for people on the team, regardless of the company's position. the manager is, effectively, the ceo of that team, and has to push to get the best results possible. if that means ensuring a higher salary to maintain quality, then so be it. the owner/snr manager can push back, of course, based on the needs of the company vs the needs of the company from that team.

Comment: i would be surprised if the push back was ever "it is coming out of your pay", that's incredibly short sighted. the push back is more *likely* to be "no", without a proper reason. the proper reason, of course, is that *one-off recruiter payments don't appear in fiscal projections*, while *pay rises for team members appear in fiscal projections*. In this way, the owner/board/vc would have questions about what is going on if they saw pay rises - or just a higher burn rate.

Comment: and of course, nobody is going to scare away the money because some developers are leaving - it's simpler to pay a recruiter and then make that payment invisible. nobody is going to tell a team lead/manager this though.

Comment: sorry, i downvoted because of the "you might be asked to pay for it", which is just really really unlikely.

Comment: @bharal I never said you would be asked, I said I would not ask unless I was willing to.

Comment: @SaggingRufus why would you not ask unless you were willing to? ie what response to you asking would mean that your unwillingness to take a pay cut would be a problem?

Comment: I wouldn't ask someone to do something I am not willing to do. If I am not willing to take a pay cut for it, why should they? This is different than a developer saying "I am worth $X and unless I get it I am leaving" this is a 3rd party asking for money from someone who likely doesn't have it. Being one of the only people getting a raise, I would say if you are going to ask, you should be willing to do it yourself. It might not be a popular opinion, but its mine.

Comment: @SaggingRufus I don't follow.  If the manager won't stay when given a pay cut or not given a raise, that's just what the managees are doing.  The manager isn't trying to talk people out of quitting for better pay while getting a raise, and so is doing what he or she is expecting employees to do.  If you're talking about a pay cut for the owner, that's ridiculous.  The owner(s) get paid out of revenue minus expenses, and if people contributing to the company leave because of low pay, then revenue is going to go down if they were worth hiring in the first place.

Comment: @DavidThornley What I am saying is don't ask for a raise for all of your employees unless you have a way to recoup the costs.

Comment: @SaggingRufus That makes no sense.  It's not this manager's job to manage the corporate finances.  There is no reason why costs need to be held at some arbitrary level.  They need to be justified, but OP has a good justification.  This is not asking the owner(s) to take a pay cut - and, even if it was, the owner(s) take the risks involved in business, and the employees should not be expected to take the risks without having the same rewards.